# Should i use Firebase custom Auth or Google OpenID OAuth to authenticate users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I need to build a custom auth system with and i don't know what to choose between Firebase Auth and Google OAuth/OpenID.

I don't want my users to sign in through google accounts nor facebook nor twitter etc.

I want to use my own user database to authenticate my users.

So what is the best and more secure, reliable,scalable option to setup this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing list of user credentials (e.g. Active Directory, LDAP or a database with user names and passwords) you can authenticate those users yourself and then tell Firebase about them with Custom Authentication tokens.

Using Google authentication makes no sense in that case, since the credentials you have are not for Google accounts.

Comment: Thanks. So google oauth is only for authenticate google users ? No way to setup a custom auth if i understand ?

Comment: If you want users to sign in with your Firebase app with their Google account, use Google sign-in. If you have an existing list of user credentials: mint custom tokens. The two have nothing to do with each other, aside from the fact that Firebase Authentication can work with both Google sign-in tokens and custom authentication tokens.